# Handling null value in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have `pyspark dataframe` with some data and i want to `substring` some data of a column, that column also contain some `null` value.
here is my dataframe

```
+-------------+
|          Name|
+--------------+
| Asia201909284|
|    US20190928|
|Europ201909287|
|          null|
|     something|
|       nothing|
+--------------+
```

all i want to eliminate `Asia, US, Europ` from column `Name`

Here is my code that I already tried.

```
fun_asia = udf(lambda x: x[4:len(x)])
fun_us = udf(lambda x: x[2:len(x)])
fun_europ = udf(lambda x: x[5:len(x)])
df1.withColumn("replace", \
               when(df1.Name.isNull(),df1.Name)\
               .when(df1.Name.like("Asia%"),fun_asia(col('Name')))\
               .when(df1.Name.like("US%"),fun_us(col('Name')))\
               .when(df1.Name.like("Europ%"),fun_europ(col('Name')))
               .otherwise(df1.Name)
              ).show()
```

It worked properly if there is no `null` value in that column. but if there is some `null` value it gave a error like `len()`  cant calculate null value.

Error massage

`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Things that i confused why its calling fun also for `null` value.
and how can i overcome my problem and get the result i want, any help appreciate.

Actual result that i want

```
+--------------+---------+
|          Name|  replace|
+--------------+---------+
| Asia201909284|201909284|
|    US20190928| 20190928|
|Europ201909287|201909287|
|          null|     null|
|     something|something|
|       nothing|  nothing|
+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: Why don't you drop the null values?

Comment: Its demo dataframe thats why i only show one column, but in my real dataframe there is more then one column, so i need that record that also have null values.

Comment: I think I have provided correct solution below. Please try it. If it helps, please upvote and select. Try the second solution which I think is better in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is using a `when` with the `isNull()` condition to handle the `when column is null` condition:

```
df1.withColumn("replace", \
               when(df1.Name.like("Asia%"),fun_asia(col('Name')))\
               .when(df1.Name.like("US%"),fun_us(col('Name')))\
               .when(df1.Name.like("Europ%"),fun_europ(col('Name')))
               .when(df1.Name.isNull(), df1.Name)
               .otherwise(df1.Name)
              ).show()
```

### EDIT2 :

You can change your udf to handle the nulls:

```
fun_asia = udf(lambda x: x[4:len(x)] if x else None)
fun_us = udf(lambda x: x[2:len(x)] if x else None)
fun_europ = udf(lambda x: x[5:len(x)] if x else None)
df1.withColumn("replace", \
               when(df1.Name.isNull(),df1.Name)\
               .when(df1.Name.like("Asia%"),fun_asia(col('Name')))\
               .when(df1.Name.like("US%"),fun_us(col('Name')))\
               .when(df1.Name.like("Europ%"),fun_europ(col('Name')))
               .otherwise(df1.Name)
              ).show()
+--------------+---------+
|          Name|  replace|
+--------------+---------+
| Asia201909284|201909284|
|    US20190928| 20190928|
|Europ201909287|201909287|
|          null|     null|
|     something|something|
|       nothing|  nothing|
+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,
1st of all i need that row with null value, so i cant drop, and my question was how can i handle `null` value not to drop or delete.
and i also try with `isNull()` option(2nd part of your answer) but result is same.sorry i forgot to mention it.

Comment: For your kind information 1st solution works but it drop `null` row, that is not my solution,
and 2nd one is not correct,

Comment: @SohelReza Please see update demonstration. I think it should work as your expected result

Comment: Sorry to say that, you are not getting my point,please watch my demo data carefully , then you will realize I cant just simply replace my entire data, as you did in your last solution, and  also i dont know how many char will be after that part i want to eliminate. Please read my question carefully again.

Comment: @SohelReza The 2nd solution doesn't drop any rows, doesn't replace anything. It only replaces what you want to replace, if there is `null` it returns `null`, otherwise it returns `df.Name`. Please read the solution carefully. The demonstration is an example and not your solution

Comment: @SohelReza Try the second solution

Comment: I was looking exactly what you done with 2nd solution , thank you so much for your kind time. and Sorry for my previous rude comment.

Comment: @SohelReza Now you do